# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (ActiveMerchant)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, activemerchant

After filling payment information, when I click on 'place order' I get this error

> > NoMethodError in OrdersController#create
> >
> > undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

OrdersController

```
def create
 @order = Order.new(order_params)
 @order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)
 credit_card = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(params[:credit_card])

 respond_to do |format|
  if @order.save
    Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
    session[:cart_id] = nil
    format.html { redirect_to category_url(Category.first), notice: 'Thank you for your order.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

order model:

```
attr_accessor :card_no, :card_cvv, :expiry_date
```

I'm guessing i need to group :card_no, :card_cvv and :expiry_date in a data structure labelled 'credit_card' but I don't know how. Thanks!

Edit:

> > NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
> >
> > app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:32:in `new'
> >
> > app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:32:in `create'
> >
> > Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/........

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: No I have not. Pls???

Comment: Could you add the whole error you get? to get a better idea on which and what happens.

Comment: That's actually the whole error message, but it pointed to this line:  credit_card = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(params[:credit_card])

Comment: And in the console, what does it print?

Comment: Added an update above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146376/discussion-between-sebastian-palma-and-johnnydevv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the params according to what you're sending from your form, so, if you want to access to them, you must take the params from the `order` root, that's to say, the `card_no` will be `params[:order][:card_no]`, and this way all of them.

And in order to make use of the ActiveMerchant gem and to create a new "CreditCard", you need to pass there your values received from the form, something like:

```
credit_card = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
  :first_name         => params[:order][:first_name],
  :last_name          => params[:order][:last_name],
  :number             => params[:order][:card_cvv],
  :month              => params[:order][:month],
  :year               => Time.now.year+1, # documentation value
  :verification_value => '000' # documentation value
)
```